# Resizing checkbox in form group in Laravel

Tags: laravel, resize, laravel-5.5

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="white-box">
        {{ Form::open(['route' => ['resources.select'], 'method' => 'ANY', 'role' => 'select']) }}
        <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('category_label', 'Categories : ') }} &nbsp;&nbsp;
                {{ Form::select('category_select', $category_select, ['class'=>'form-control']) }} &nbsp;&nbsp;
                {{ Form::button('Submit',['type'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-r-10', 'id'=>'select_resource']) }}
        </div>
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my code. I have three different divisions that look the same. When I tried to change to a grid view, The select boxes stay overlapping the div block.
I want them to stay within the block in the view.

Comment: This is not a Laravel question but a CSS/bootstrap one. Unsolvable for anybody. Because we don't know what "white-box", "wave-effect" and other classes behold.

Comment: The waves effect can be applied to any element. To put the waves effect on buttons, you just have to put the class waves-effect on to the buttons.

Comment: White box just puts all the contents around a white box

Comment: How can I solve it using CSS/Bootstrap??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your select is overlapping is because you are missing null as a parameter in the declaration.

Change this line;

```
{{ Form::select('category_select', $category_select, ['class'=>'form-control']) }} &nbsp;&nbsp;
```

to this;

```
{{ Form::select('category_select', $category_select, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) }}
```

Also you do not need the `&nbsp;` to style the form. A more efficient way of creating the form in your question would be like the example below

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="white-box">
        {{ Form::open(['route' => ['resources.select'], 'method' => 'ANY', 'role' => 'select']) }}
        <div class="form-group">
           {{ Form::label('category_label', 'Categories : ') }}
           {{ Form::select('category_select', $category_select, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) }}
        </div>
        {{ Form::button('Submit',['type'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-r-10', 'id'=>'select_resource']) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
</div>
```